# Android after parse user logout it is fetching old user information

Tags: android, parse-platform

I use `ParseUser.logout()` to logout the current user. After that, I delete all records in database. I want to display data only for new users.

Code used to delete the details

getContentResolver().delete(UserDetails.URI,null, null);

Then I login with

```
ParseFacebookUtils.logInWithReadPermissionsInBackground(getApplicationcontext(), permissions, callback);
```

If I login with another user, the server is fetching the old user's information. I checked the log for parse site, which shows I changed my master to new user but it fetches information of old user.I call the background service using sync adapter I reset the adapter. But If close and reopen my app means it works correctly.

Can anybody help me to solve this. Any help will be appreciated and thanks in advance.

Comment: Please show some example code to better illustrate your problem, along with what you have tried already in your efforts to fix this.